# Search in all vertices by one specific field value

Tags: redisgraph

I would like to know if it's possible to search in all vertices by one specifig field value, without naming each vertex explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify the label it is possible to query all nodes via property.

Say I have two labels Actors(properties: ActorId and Name) and Movies(properties: tconst and primaryTitle) in a database called IMDB and I want to search for either movies or actors named Kevin Bacon.

I can query across both node labels.  However, if the property names are different this makes little sense and will not utilize the indices.

```
> GRAPH.QUERY IMDB "MATCH (a{Name: 'Kevin Bacon'}) RETURN a limit 1"
1) 1) 1) "a.ActorId"
      2) "a.Name"
      3) "a.tconst"
      4) "a.primaryTitle"
   2) 1) "nm0000102"
      2) "Kevin Bacon"
      3) "NULL"
      4) "NULL"
```

Comment: Awesome! Works for me 